# UTC time in java?

Tags: java, datetime, utc, datetime-conversion

How can I get UTC value in Java of any given time and date with the respective time-zone?

Say for example my current time zone is `Asia/Kolkata`, now how can I get UTC value of say `1.00 am on 21/07/2018`?

Comment: this can't possibly be a not-duplicate...

Comment: @lelloman Indeed.. I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java

Comment: You want to input a date and specify your timezone, and be able to see what UTC time correpond ?

Comment: yes exactly I want to give inputs @azro

Comment: Edit your question with an example of : given input and expectd output

Comment: Possible duplicate or near-duplicate of (1) [How to get time from user with respect to timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052157/how-to-get-time-from-user-with-respect-to-timezone), (2) [TimeStamp.valueOf() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809816/timestamp-valueof-method) and/or (3) [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [As the help page says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you are supposed to search and research before asking. You are also likely to find a good answer faster that way.

Comment: @user2396066 Mark correct answer

Answer (score 2):

For getting currect time in UTC.

```
 Instant.now()  // Current time in UTC.
```

For getting current time in any desired TimeZone.

```
 ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )   // Current time in your ZoneId.
```

> Kolkata Example :

```
ZoneId zoneKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zoneDTKolkata = instant.atZone( zoneKolkata ) ;
```

To adjust back to UTC, extract an `Instant` from the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zoneDTKolkata.toInstant() ;
```

You can adjust from UTC to a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zoneDTKolkata = instant.atZone( zoneKolkata ) ;
```

Comment: An answer should contains explanation on the code it contains.

Comment: added the explanation  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java 8 time API instead of the older API (ie Date & SimpleDateFormat solution proposed by rajadilipkolli)

```
// System time (ie, your operating system time zone)
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

// Time in Asia/Kolkata
ZonedDateTime kolkata = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

// Time in UTC
OffsetDateTime utc = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: That will give the same wall-clock time in UTC. I thought the asker was after the same point in time, but s/he can better tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("h.mm a 'on' dd/MM/uuuu")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    String localDateTimeString = "1.00 am on 21/07/2018";
    Instant i = LocalDateTime.parse(localDateTimeString, formatter)
            .atZone(zone)
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println("UTC value is: " + i);
```

This prints:

> UTC value is: 2018-07-20T19:30:00Z

I wasn’t sure whether you needed to parse the exact string you gave, `1.00 am on 21/07/2018`, into a date-time object, but in case I have shown how. The challenge is that `am` is in lowercase. In order to specify case insensitive parsing I needed to go through a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

As you can see, the code converts to an `Instant`, which is the modern way to represent a point in time in Java. `Instant.toString` always prints the time in UTC. The `Z` at the end means UTC. If you want a date-time that is more explicitly in UTC you may use

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(localDateTimeString, formatter)
            .atZone(zone)
            .toInstant()
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println("UTC value is: " + odt);
```

The output is similar, only `OffsetDateTime` leaves out the seconds if they are 0 (zero):

> UTC value is: 2018-07-20T19:30Z

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.